# Как обойти ошибку Undefined offset:?

Tags: php

error_reporting не предлагать!

Суть вот в чем? страница **a** инклюдит страницу **b**, до проведения определенных действий которые не включают POST и GET запросы, нужно скрыть ошибку **Undefined offset**:.
Ошибка появляется в результате отсутствующего параметра в массиве. Выполнив действие ошибка конечно пропадает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_POST['some_undefined_key'])){//Вместо $_POST можно любой другой массив, который провоцирует ошибку
$_POST['some_undefined_key'] = '';
}
```

И... да. Это надо сделать для всех ключей(можно в цикле), которые может запросить страница

Comment: Заработался я) совсем забыл за !isset пробывал просто isset.
Спасибо.

Comment: бывает :)